# UserForm_Initialize - Need help troubleshooting Run-time error '91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I can't seem to figure out why my UserForm code fails at the very end of the procedure.  The end result is perfect.  Here is what I'm trying to accomplish...

1) Using the active workbook, the procedure identifies the sheet names in the workbook and displays them in the Listbox, which is located on the userform.
 [UserForm Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r3FB.png)

2) Once the sheet is selected, the user will click the "Select Sheet" CommandButton

3) The CommanButton activates the sheet, renames the sheet to "LegacyBillHist"

4) The form closes, and cell A2 is selected

I get the Run-time error 91 message on the very last line.

I've tried a few different approaches to resolve the issue, but I can't seem to figure this one out using the info in StackOverflow and other sites.    Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code..

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Name = "LegacyBillHist"
    Unload BillSelect

End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
        Next sh

    Load BillSelect
    BillSelect.Show

    sh.Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot select a range on a sheet which isn't active.

Comment: You are getting an error because of `sh.Range("A2").Select`. `sh` is nothing

Comment: @TimWilliams beat me to it :D

Answer (score 1):

Mathieu

Great info.  I ended up changing my approach significantly.  However, I have a different problem that I haven't been able to figure out.  Here is the Code...I got it from the article you referenced...

```
Option Explicit
Private cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    OnCancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
   cancelled = True
   Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
   ActiveSheet.Name = "LegacyBillHist"

   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("LegacyBillHist")

   ws.Activate
   ws.Range("A1").Select

   UserForm1.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim lastSheet As Worksheet
   Dim sh As Worksheet

     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
     For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
     ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
     Set lastSheet = sh
     Next

   UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Everything works great up to the End Sub under the CommandButton1 routine.  Instead of hiding UserForm1, it reopens the form.

I tried incorporation the code you provided, but it keeps cycling through until I get the Out of stack space error 28.  Perhaps I'm not putting it in the correct sequence.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim lastSheet As Worksheet
   Dim sh As Worksheet

     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
     For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
     ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
     Set lastSheet = sh
     Next

    With New UserForm1'<~ forms are objects too; avoid using their global state
      .Show
    End With
 End Sub
```

Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     For Each sh In wb.Sheets
>     ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
>     Next sh
> ```

The object `sh` only ever makes sense *inside* the `For...Next` loop.

**In theory**, as per language specifications, `sh` **should** indeed still hold a reference to the last item in the iterated collection:

> - When the `<for-each-statement>` has finished executing, the value of `<bound-variable-expression>` is the data value of the last element in `<collection>`.
>
> <sub>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/MS-VBAL/b132463a-fd25-4143-8fc7-a443930e0651</sub>

However it appears when VBA was implemented, that bullet point wasn't: a `For Each` variable that is `Nothing` before the loop, will still be `Nothing` after the loop - and any member call made against `Nothing` will always raise error 91.

To be honest, I think it's better that way, too: it forces your code to be more explicit:

```
Dim lastSheet As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In wb.Worksheets '<~ note: 'Sheets' collection can have charts, not just worksheets
    ListBox1.AddItem sh.Name
    Set lastSheet = sh
Next

With New BillSelect '<~ forms are objects too; avoid using their global state
    .Show
End With

lastSheet.Activate
lastSheet.Range("A1").Select
```

Note: `New`ing-up the `BillSelect` can surface hidden bugs in your form code, [read this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for more info.

---

The `Initialize` handler shouldn't be doing this work, **especially** if you don't `New` up the form and use its *default instance*: you do not control when that default instance gets created, VBA does.

Given this code:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

If no code ever referred to `UserForm1` before, then the `Initialize` handler runs *at* `UserForm1`, *before* the reference is returned to the caller and the `.Show` call runs; if the form's default instance isn't destroyed, then the next time the form is shown, *the initialize handler will not run again*, because the instance is already initialized.

Consider implementing your logic in the `Activate` handler instead, which will make the logic run *after* the `.Show` call is entered, and *every time* the form is activated (and since that's a modal dialog, that means every time the form is actually shown).